# Adding single quotes to values in object (javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a string like this :

```
"[ {name: foo, type: int}, {name: status, type: string}, 
{name: boo, type: string}, {name: koo, type: data} ]"
```

and i need to add single quotes for values inside every object , to become like this string :

```
"[ {name: 'foo', type: 'int'}, {name: 'status', type: 
'string'}, {name: 'boo', type: 'string'}, {name: 'koo', 
type: 'data'} ]"
```

i have tried to use `eval` , `JSON.parse` , but didn't see the expected result , is there any idea to do this and just add the single quotes for values in objects ?

This is the whole JSON , but i only need the fields part .

```
{
"success": true,
    "count": 1,
"data": [
    {
    "res": "extend: 'someCode', fields: [ {name: foo, type: int}, 
           {name: status, type: string}, 
           {name: boo, type: string}, {name: koo, type: data} ]"
    }     
       ]
}
```

Comment: Correct way? that's asks for opinions. But, there is no magic way, you'll have to parse the string manually to produce your result.

Comment: How was this string produced?

Comment: @RandyCasburn i was looking for ideas of course !!
can you explain more clear?because i receive this string from server and there is an automated process i can not change it manually

Comment: Looks like someone did not know how to produce JSON proper. Why can't you tell them? Are you absolutely certain this is what is returned?

Comment: The server is producing invalid JSON.  Fix that, don't try repairing broken JSON.

Comment: actually there is a complete JSON , i will add the whole in question again , 
the important thing is i only need this part of the json , i can cut the whole code before `field` .

Comment: @mplungjan i added the whole JSON which is produced by server . but i only need the fields part

Comment: It is very invalid... Is there no way to fix it on the server?

Comment: @mplungjan you mean even the whole JSON which i receive from server is invalid ? i can not fix it , i have to consult with backend team

Comment: Your backend team is producing invalid JSON, yes.  The field names *must* be in quotes.  String values *must* be in quotes.

Comment: @Amy so the right one , after field there should be quotes for keys and values in objects ,if i am right ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with a regex:

```js
const val = `[ {name: foo, type: int}, {name: status, type: string}, 
    {name: boo, type: string}, {name: koo, type: data} ]`


console.log(val.replace(/(\w+)\s*\:\s*(\w+)/g, "$1: '$2'"))
```

Seems to produce a valid javascript array:

```
> eval(val.replace(/(\w+)\s*\:\s*(\w+)/g, "$1: '$2'"))
[ { name: 'foo', type: 'int' },
  { name: 'status', type: 'string' },
  { name: 'boo', type: 'string' },
  { name: 'koo', type: 'data' } ]
```

Might have to tweak it to suit your use case.

Comment: Here are the tweaks needed : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56294154/295783

Answer (score 0):

Here are the tweaks needed to fix [Richard's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56293927/295783)

```js
let val = `[ {name: foo, type: int}, {name: status, type: string}, {name: boo, type: string}, {name: koo, type: data} ]`

val = val.replace(/(\w+)\s*\:\s*(\w+)/g, "\"$1\": \"$2\"")
console.log(JSON.parse(val))
```

Here is a correct JS object from the "JSON" you posted

```js
{
  "success": "true",
    "count": 1,
    "data": [{
      "res": { "extend": "someCode" }, 
      "fields": [ 
        {"name": "foo",  "type": "int"}, 
        {"name": "status", "type": "string"}, 
        {"name": "boo", "type": "string"}, 
        {"name": "koo", "type": "data" } 
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks , i will check this

Comment: i asked the backend team about this and they said that `data` has only `res` as a result

Answer (score -1):

Regexp replacement may be easy for this.

```js
var s = "[ {name: foo, type: int}, {name: status, type: string}, {name: boo, type: string}, {name: koo, type: data} ]";
console.log(s.replace(/:[ ]*([^ ,}]+)/gi, ": '$1'"));
```

```
> "[ {name: 'foo', type: 'int'}, {name: 'status', type: 'string'}, {name: 'boo', type: 'string'}, {name: 'koo', type: 'data'} ]"
```

Please see below too.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace